# Understanding recurrence in algorithm design

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I have some ambiguity in recurrence, so I'll set the following questions:

(1) What does it really mean saying recurrence? Does it apply **only** when talking about divide and conquer?

(2) Assume I have this simple Algorithm:

```
sum <- 0
for i<- 1 to n
  sum <- sum + 1
return sum
```

How do I write a recurrence for this algorithm? I mean I understand this algorithm just does summation but how to transfer this into recurrence?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what syntax you are using, but I suppose it would go something line this.

```
sub sum(n)  
   if n > 0 
     return 1 + sum(n-1)
   else 
     return 0
   end if
end sub
```

Comment: Ok so recurrence is to make an algorithm recursively calls itself to solve the problem. Got it! Isn't supposed to return `n + sum(n-1)` ?

Comment: @NP-hard Sure, thanks. I'm finding that, the older I get, the more I do things line this.

Comment: @MikeM. - If you check out the original algorithm, you'll see its computing $1+1+1+ \cdots + 1$ instead of $n + (n-1) + (n-2) + \cdots + 1$.

Comment: Oh yes right .. I am sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sequence of numbers $a_0,a_1,\dots , a_n, \dots$ and you have a relation between any $a_n$ and the terms preceding it, meaning that the "ancestor" terms generate the new one, that is a recurrence.
 Then, once you  know the values of the "pioneers" (those who are not generated by anyone), you can determine *recursively* all the generated sequel.
In the example you made, the recurrence is
$S_n=S_{n-1}+1$   given that $S_0=0$, more formally $S_n=S_{n-1}+1 \quad | \; S_0=0$

Comment: Thank you very much. Well explained